# Maven won't recognize certain Kotlin classes in Java project

Tags: java, maven, kotlin

I have a Java project that incorporates some classes in Kotlin code. There are actually two Kotlin files, each in different folders and each a different package.

When doing a `mvn clean package`, Kotlin file A is recognized and compiled into the project, but Kotlin file B is not.

Strangely, B was compiled in earlier, but I converted some Groovy files to Java to avoid [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Babel). Those new Java files reference the classes in B, and it is their compilation that is producing the errors.

I've checked and double-checked package names. To see if B's folder was being noticed by Maven, I even converted one of the data classes in B to Java and left it in the same folder. Suddenly that class was recognized.

What's going on here? Do I have a POM problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add the following to my POM under the section for the Kotlin plug in:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <executions>
        <!-- Replacing default-compile as it is treated specially by maven -->
        <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <!-- Replacing default-testCompile as it is treated specially by maven -->
        <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>java-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>java-test-compile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals> <goal>testCompile</goal> </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This was according to the the documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html#compiling-kotlin-and-java-sources).